# Bootstrap multilingual

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3, multilingual

I am working on a simple web site based on ASP.NET MVC and Bootstrap.
The site contains the static HTML text which I've put into the views.
Can I somehow make this to be multilingual and what is the correct approach of doing that (e.g. how can i switch from one language to another based on user changing the language on site). I will translate the contents to the different languages.

Is there a good way to achieve that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: show some code you have done already

Comment: Here is a small snippet if this really matters of 'about us' page
`code`@{
`code`    ViewBag.Title = "About";
`code`}
<div class="featurette-divider"></div>
<div class="container">
        <h2>About us</h2>
    <footer>
        <p class="pull-right">&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year</p>
    </footer>
</div>

Comment: I was thinking whether it would be a good idea to use controller viewBag and set the language in viewBag which is then afterwards used in the view to show / hide the correct language depending on the Language. Would this be a good idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could achieve this in a following way:

- Added an action filter where I did set the culture (and store this in
  a cookie) on a thread;
- Added resources (default plus the resources required for languages I support);
- The pages contain the text which is taken from the resources (the correct language is taken once this is set on a thread or a default is taken if no resource were found);
- To support he language picker I've added the LanguageController which is saving the culture to the cookie;
- I call to language controller using ActionLink from my layout and set the language I support.

Hope this helps someone